# fixed header table deform when resizing window

Tags: html, css

this fixed-header table deforms column when resizing window horizontally. Is there way to stop that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table th {
            border-left: 1px solid blue;
        }
        table th,
        table td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: left;
            border-left:1px solid blue;
        }

        table th, table td {
            width: 150px;
        }
        table thead tr {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        }
        table tbody {
            display: block;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>pick_up_location</th>
                <th>destination</th>
                <th>instruction</th>
                <th>created_at</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>12322</td>
                <td>Whanga Road</td>
                <td>Crescent Street</td>
                <td>Call when arrive</td>
                <td>123442342331</td>
                <td>comming</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind this fixed-header table. Mean when you have 100 rows. you can scroll the row but the header position is fixed. The display block attributes can not be removed.

UPDATE:

With Mark answer, the table looks fine but still deform at small screen. A screenshot of it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To don't have problems with resizing you have to work in height and width with %.

Like : width: 30%;
       height: 40%;

Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not apply an explicit width or height to tag. Instead, give it:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

Comment: for table {
            width: 100%;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

Answer (score 0):

just modify the last two ccs declarations as follows:

```
table{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    table tbody {

        position : relative;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `word-break: break-all;` to all the cells makes your code work (almost, since all characters are not of the same width)
See https://jsfiddle.net/3wn1zzfn/
Your problem is that when it is not possible to fit all cells in a table, the `width: 150px;` is overridden, and widths are now based on length of the line.

Comment: If you want it to work at low screen sizes, you should consider reducing font size

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you are applying `display: block`, you shouldn't use it on tables. Also remove px values on tables. use %, or remove it at all

Remove these lines of code:

```
    table th, 
      table td {
        /*width: 150px*/
    }
     table thead tr {
        /*display: block;
        position: relative;*/
    }
    table tbody {
        /*display: block;*/
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
```

Here a codepen to show it:
http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/qNYork?editors=1100

---

--EDIT--

before -1 please can you tell me what's wrong with my solution, to improve it?